# Passing variable in function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When you pass variables in Javascript functions, what is the difference between '$name' and 'name'.

For example,

```
var myFunction = function(name){
  name.a = "a"; 
};

var myFunction = function($name){
  $name.b = "b";
};
```

Comment: There's no difference. `$` is a valid character for use in a parameter or variable name, but it has no special meaning. It's not an operator.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference in your example is the name, it has no special purpose.

However you might have seen the `$name` styled variables in jQuery examples in which it's normal to name selected elements (`$('a')`) as, for example, `$links`.